# github octopus merge diff does not match branch comparison

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

The diff displayed by github on an octopus merge ( https://github.com/ceph/ceph/commit/e54834bfac3c38562987730b317cb1944a96005b ) does not match the diff of the two branches that only differ by this octopus merge ( https://github.com/ceph/ceph/compare/firefly...firefly-backports?expand=1. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diffs on merge commits on github show the diff between the current commit and the first parent (or in other words what the merge applied to the checked out branch)

Therefore it would be this diff: https://github.com/ceph/ceph/compare/e539971e2d528b4de6009ea44565f037acb2be66...firefly-backports

What github is showing with https://github.com/ceph/ceph/compare/firefly...firefly-backports?expand=1
is the output of `git diff firefly...firefly-backports` which [by the manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) is the diff from the common ancestor of these two branches to the tip of firefly-backports. Since these branches are divergent, The common ancestor of these branches is in fact https://github.com/ceph/ceph/commit/555cc42fc826fd801f0d45187429079d4072d129

so what you're seeing in that compare is all changes from 555cc42 to firefly-backports.

Comment: it would be nice to ask github to either not display this in case of an octopus merge to avoid confusion. or do the better thing which is what you did : find the common ancestor and diff from it.